# how to update array in async manner in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a `data` array in my component of `angular10` app in which i want to add `city` in each `object` of `data` array. So for that i have a `function` in a `service` like this

```
getCityFromLatLong(lat: any, long: any): Observable<any> {
  let city = '';
  let cityObs = new Observable((observer: Observer<any>) => {
     this.geoCoder.geocode({ 'location': { lat: lat, lng: long } }, (results, status) => {
        if (status === 'OK' && results.length && results[0]) {
           let address = results.filter(r => r.types.includes('locality'))[0];
           if (address) {
             city = address.address_components[0].long_name;
             observer.next(city);
           }
        }
     });
  });
  return cityObs;
}
```

and in my `component.ts` i have the following

```
data = [
 {
   code: ""
   datetime: "2021-03-06T08:53:00.000Z"
   lat: "44.5753184"
   location: "Pakistan Town Rawalpindi, Islamabad, Islamabad Capital Territory, Pakistan"
   locationType: "dropoff"
   long: "79.143074"
 },
 {
   code: ""
   datetime: "2021-03-06T08:53:00.000Z"
   lat: "33.5753184"
   location: "Pakistan Town Rawalpindi, Islamabad, Islamabad Capital Territory, Pakistan"
   locationType: "dropoff"
   long: "71.143074"
 },
 {
   code: ""
   datetime: "2021-03-06T08:53:00.000Z"
   lat: "33.5753184"
   location: "Pakistan Town Rawalpindi, Islamabad, Islamabad Capital Territory, Pakistan"
   locationType: "dropoff"
   long: "63.143074"
 },
 {
   code: ""
   datetime: "2021-03-06T08:53:00.000Z"
   lat: "33.5753184"
   location: "Pakistan Town Rawalpindi, Islamabad, Islamabad Capital Territory, Pakistan"
   locationType: "dropoff"
   long: "23.143074"
 },
]

async addCityToAddress(addressArr: any[]){
  for await(let [index, item] of addressArr.entries()){
     this._utilService.getCityFromLatLong(parseFloat(item.lat), parseFloat(item.long)).subscribe(res => {
    addressArr[index].city = res
     });
  }
 return [...addressArr];
}


ngOnInit(){
   this.data = this.addCityToAddress(this.allLocations);
}
```

But it's not adding the city in each `object` of the `array`. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you creating the observer?, algo you can use find instead of filter. Are you sure this condition is true at some point .. if (address)?

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure for the need to convert the observable to promise. Instead you could emit `.complete` in the observable and combine all the observables using the RxJS `forkJoin` function.

Try the following

**Service**

```js
getCityFromLatLong(lat: any, long: any): Observable<any> {
  let city = '';
  return new Observable((observer: Observer<any>) => {
     this.geoCoder.geocode({ 'location': { lat: lat, lng: long } }, (results, status) => {
        if (status === 'OK' && results.length && results[0]) {
           let address = results.filter(r => r.types.includes('locality'))[0];
           if (address) {
             city = address.address_components[0].long_name;
             observer.next(city);
           }
        }
        observer.complete();    // <-- complete the observable here
     });
  });
}
```

**Component**

```js
addCityToAddress(addressArr: any[]): Observable<any> {  // <-- return `Observable` here
  return forkJoin(addressArr.map(item =>
    this._utilService.getCityFromLatLong(
      parseFloat(item.lat),
      parseFloat(item.long)
    ).pipe(map(city => ({ ...item, city: city })))  // <-- add `city` property to the object
  ));
}

ngOnInit() {
   this.addCityToAddress(this.allLocations).subscribe({  // <-- subscribe here
     next: res => {
       this.data = res;
     }
   });
}
```

#### Update: debug with `tap`

Try to `console.log` the emission from the observable

```js
addCityToAddress(addressArr: any[]): Observable<any> {  // <-- return `Observable` here
  return forkJoin(addressArr.map(item =>
    this._utilService.getCityFromLatLong(
      parseFloat(item.lat),
      parseFloat(item.long)
    ).pipe(
      tap({
        next: (res) => console.log(item, res),
        error: (error) => { },
        complete: () => console.log('Complete:', item)
      }),
      map(city => ({ ...item, city: city }))  // <-- add `city` property to the object
    )  
  ));
}
```

Comment: `entries().map` is throwing this error `Property map  does not exist on type IterableIterator<[number, any]>` inside `addCityToAddress ` function

Comment: The `entries()` isn't required since `map()` suffices. I've updated the code. Please try again if it works for you.

Comment: It's not working. Subscriber is not calling even one time.

Comment: i am doing this in `ngOnInit`        

`this.addCityToAddress(this.allLocations).subscribe({  // <-- subscribe here
        next: res => {
          console.log('res : ', res)
          this.allLocations = res;
          console.log(this.allLocations);
        }
      });` 

but none of the console line is printing.

Comment: For the `forkJoin` to emit all the source observables _must_ complete. Try to put a `console.log` right before the `observer.complete()` and check if it's getting print for each element of the array.

Comment: Yes it's printing there.

Comment: Then I'm not exactly sure. Try to setup a minimal reproducible example (eg. using Stackblitz).

Comment: here is https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-48vtmd example of what i am trying to do. Please place your google api key

Comment: Good question. And I don't have a billing account. Last I remembered Google allows keyless requests for developments purposes with low res images. Not sure if it's still available and not sure how to integrate it in Angular.

Comment: can you see the code? if any thing is wrong there?

Comment: @FahadSubzwari: I've updated the code to print emissions from each of the observable. Check if `Complete` is logged for all the elements of the array.

Comment: it's just printing `console.log('Complete:', item)` only once

Comment: That is the issue then. It should print for all the elements (and the corresponding observables). Make the callback to `geocode()` is called for each element of the array.

Comment: @FahadSubzwari: Modify to what exactly?

Comment: which you are suggesting. Because i didn't understand that what were you saying to make the callback to `geocode()`

Comment: I mean this function: `(results, status) => { ... }`. Make sure it's triggered for all the elements of the array. Try to do a `console.log` inside it.

Comment: Yes `(results, status) => { ... }` is trigging for each element of the array.